# the error is-> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

**i need here to do something in the database when this condition happen but i always get this error !!**

```
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            int quantity = reader.GetInt32(2);
            string pro = reader.GetString(0);
            if (quantity <= 0)
            {
                SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM[Products] WHERE Quantity =@user", s);

                sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", quantity);
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
```

Comment: You have `reader = command.ExecuteReader();` twice
and you can move reader.Close() out of while

Comment: If you want a complete solution, post more code.  We need to know what "s" is, and what command is.

Comment: still the same thing

Answer (score 3):

It appears you are calling the same `command.ExecuteReader()` twice. 
Remove the second `reader = command.ExecuteReader();` and it should work

Comment: Also, don't close the reader inside the while loop, close it after the loop.  The way it is now will cause an exception once the 2nd reader is removed as suggested by @Aviatrix

Comment: He actually needs two data readers.  He uses information from the one data reader to query SQL again.  Instead, inside the loop he needs to declare a second reader with a different name.

Comment: He's executing the same command though, so the first one will have the same thing the 2nd one would have hence why we agreed to remove the 2nd one.  There is no code shown to indicate the command changed between the two calls.

Comment: @Ryios - Yes, I see.  I was thinking that the SqlCommand inside the loop also used a reader.  I failed to notice that it was just a Delete command which would not need a reader, so calling ExecuteReader again and closing it inside the loop is indeed the cause of the problem.

Comment: i have remove both from the loop and still the same error

Answer (score 1):

u should define two SqlConnection. u used the SqlConnection quantity 2 times before closing